# Word Addin Debug

Tags: debugging, ms-word, add-in

I have created a Word Addin for MS Word 2010. I want to debug the code. When I press Debug, a new instance of word is opened but no Addin seem to be loaded. 
I can see my addin after installing via setup(.msi).
My addin is loaded as a COM object in word in mscoree.dll not as vsto.

Comment: Wow -- I don't even know where to start -- first off -- why are you using an .MSI to debug?  that doesn't make any sense -- second off -- it's a weird VSTO nuance -- but BUILDING the app is what installs it -- hitting F5 or CTRL+F5 just launches Word and tries to attach the debugger.  Uninstall any .MSIs of your app. Try switching to Debug Mode, Clean Solution, Rebuild All (that one is important, make sure all projects are selected for build and are set to correct "bitness"), when Build completes successfully, try just running WinWord. If the add-in shows up, then F5 debug should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your setup program is putting in necessary registry keys for the add-in down: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins (or alternately down this path but in HKCU). Or, if this key is already there, ensure the HKCU entry, if exists, has LoadBehavior set to 3